# Security Token For HttpSend Activity in SP2013 (On-Premise) for calling external Web API

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, workflow-activity, sharepoint-on-prem, security-token-service

I have an On-Premise SharePoint 2013 site configured for Multi Tenancy with FBA. I have a SP 2013 workflow. In that, I need to call a Web API from another IIS site, built using ASP.Net MVC. To be able to call this Web API, I believe I need to pass the Security Token along with the Request Header. But I have no clue how to pass this while invoking the Web API or what value to be passed. Can anyone please help? There don't seem to be enough examples showing this. It will be great, if someone can provide detailed steps or walk through for the same.